# How do I make pnpm work as intended in a vscode dev container?

Tags: pnpm

I am coding in a vscode dev container, where pnpm was installed as [suggested in the docs](https://pnpm.io/installation), using curl:

```
RUN curl https://get.pnpm.io/install.sh | ENV="$HOME/.bashrc" SHELL="$(which bash)" bash -
```

Today, pnpm told me it needed an update and suggested using this command:

> Update available! 8.7.4 → 8.7.5.
>
> Changelog: https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/releases/tag/v8.7.5
>
> Run "pnpm add -g pnpm" to update.

So, I ran `pnpm add -g pnpm`, which did the update, but gave the following warning:

> Nothing to stop. No server is running for the store at
> /home/magnus/.local/share/pnpm/store/v3

That spurred me to investigate further. I found the following:

**1) First Finding**

`pnpm store path` logs: `/home/magnus/repositoryfolder/.pnpm-store/v3`.

In other words, the global store is placed inside my repository, and not in `~/.local/share/pnpm/store/v3` which is the default.

[Here from the docs](https://pnpm.io/npmrc#store-dir):

> **store-dir**
>
> The location where all the packages are saved on the disk.
>
> Default:
>
> - If the $PNPM_HOME env variable is set, then $PNPM_HOME/store
> - If the $XDG_DATA_HOME env variable is set, then $XDG_DATA_HOME/pnpm/store
> - On Windows: ~/AppData/Local/pnpm/store
> - On macOS: ~/Library/pnpm/store
> - On Linux: ~/.local/share/pnpm/store
>
> If there is a home directory on the current disk, then the store is
> created inside it. If there is no home on the disk, then the store is
> created at the root of the filesystem. For example, if installation is
> happening on a filesystem mounted at /mnt, then the store will be
> created at /mnt/.pnpm-store. The same goes for Windows systems.

[And here from a support thread](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/2719):

> When choosing a location for the global store, pnpm will start with
> ~/.pnpm-store. If pnpm cannot create a hard link from your project to
> that location, then it will try to find the directory with the
> smallest length to which it can link. It will start from your projects
> directory. So if your project is at /1/2/3/project/, pnpm will try to
> make a hard link in /1/2/3/project. Then in /1/2/3/. Then in /1/2.
> Let's say it fails to make one in /1/2. In this case the store will be
> at /1/2/3/.pnpm-store.
>
> This code is at: https://github.com/pnpm/store-path

**2) Other Findings**

- `which pnpm` logs: `/home/magnus/.local/share/pnpm/pnpm`

---

**Question**

- Why does `pnpm add pnpm -g` not recognize where my store is located?
- How do I fix it? Should I add something to the Dockerfile vscode uses to create the dev container?

---

**Notes**

I have this in `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------
# Needed to ensure pnpm binary is added to PATH.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------
SHELL='/bin/bash'

# PNPM_HOME is path to pnpm executable file (i.e. bin file)
# Had to set the path here, to its original default,
# because docker somehow overwrote it.
export PNPM_HOME="/home/magnus/.local/share/pnpm"
case ":$PATH:" in
  *":$PNPM_HOME:"*) ;;
  *) export PATH="$PNPM_HOME:$PATH" ;;
esac
```

And this in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN curl https://get.pnpm.io/install.sh | ENV="$HOME/.bashrc" SHELL="$(which bash)" bash -
ENV PATH="/home/$USER_NAME/.local/share/pnpm:${PATH}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Cause of the issue

The store and the `node_modules` directory must be on the same volume for pnpm to create hard links between the two successfully.

Say you have a project on your local filesystem at `/home/magnus/my-project`. When you use `Reopen in Dev Container` in VSCode, it binds `/home/magnus/my-project` to `/workspaces/my-project` within the container.

So when trying to resolve where to place the store, here's what happens:

| Step | Result |
| --- | --- |
| Check `/home/magnus/.local/share/pnpm` | ❌ Different filesystem to `/workspaces/my-project` |
| Check `/` | ❌ Different filesystem to `/workspaces/my-project` |
| Check `/workspaces` | ❌ Different filesystem to `/workspaces/my-project` |
| Check `/workspaces/my-project` | ✅ Same filesystem as `/workspaces/my-project` |

So the store gets created at `/workspaces/my-project/.pnpm-store/v3`.

#### Solution

Instead of using VSCode's `Reopen in Dev Container`, I used `Clone Repository in Container Volume` to clone the repo into an isolated Docker volume with no bindings (this has the added bonus of [improved disk performance](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/containers#_quick-start-open-a-git-repository-or-github-pr-in-an-isolated-container-volume)). pnpm was then happy to use parent directories for the store.

(I'm sure there's a way to solve this more reliably with the `mounts` option in `devcontainer.json`, but haven't figured that part out yet.)

---

Here's a full solution for setting up a new project that worked for me:

1. Create a new repo on github.com
2. In VSCode, press `Ctrl+Shift+P`, choose `Dev Containers: Clone Repository in Dev Container`, and select your newly-created Github repo
3. Follow the prompts to create a new `devcontainer.json` file
4. Once the container opens, create `.devcontainer/Dockerfile` with these contents (modify as you see fit):

   ```
   FROM mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/javascript-node:20

   WORKDIR /workspaces/my-project

   ENV PNPM_HOME=/workspaces/pnpm
   RUN corepack enable pnpm

   COPY pnpm-lock.yaml ./

   # optional: only needed if you've patched any packages
   COPY patches patches    

   # pre-loads required packages from pnpm-lock.yaml into the store,
   # ready to be installed with `pnpm install`
   RUN pnpm fetch
   ```
5. Update `.devcontainer/devcontainer.json` to include the following:

   ```json
   {
       "name": "my-project",
       "build": {
           "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",

           // Runs docker from the project root instead of `.devcontainer`,
           // to ensure `COPY pnpm-lock.yaml ./` works
           "context": ".."
       },

       // --offline will use the packages pre-loaded into the store
       // during `RUN pnpm fetch` in the Dockerfile
       "postCreateCommand": "pnpm install --offline"
   }
   ```
6. Commit and push

Comment: Thanks. I actually ended up fixing it by manually creating my own Docker container and attaching VSCode to it. In the Docker container i set up a `home/username/projectname` structure like I had on the host machine (though different username). I made sure `PNPM_HOME` was available inside the container as `/home/username/.local/share/pnpm`. To be absolutely sure pnpm used the right store directory, I also set `store-dir=${PNPM_HOME}/store` in `.npmrc`. See how the store location is chosen here: https://pnpm.io/npmrc#store-dir